# How can I tell PyCharm that an object is a specialization (subclass) of a type without using "isinstance"?

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, type-hinting

I have a method that receives objects that share a common superclass but are of many different subtypes. It checks the type of each object, and, depending on the type, passes it to different functions. The receiver functions are annotated to receive specific subtypes.

The object types are known ahead of time and are part of a finite set. Objects will only ever be depth-1 subclasses, not sub-subclasses.

This code is very performance critical. To avoid the overhead of calling `isinstance` multiple times when dispatching, I store the type in a variable.

However, I'm having trouble getting PyCharm to detect the "specialization" of each object based on that stored type variable. It indicates typeerrors because I'm passing objects whose type it only knows as the superclass to functions that receive specific subclasses.

For example, my code looks like this:

```py
class Superclass: ...
class Subtype1(Superclass): ...
class Subtype2(Superclass): ...
# ...many more subtypes

def receiver1(arg: Subtype1): ...
def receiver2(arg: Subtype2): ...
# ...many more receivers

def dispatch():
    item = get_item()
    item_type = type(item)
    if item_type is Subtype1:
        receiver(item)
    elif item_type is Subtype2:
        receiver2(item)
    # ... many more cases
```

With that code, PyCharm detects type mismatches on the calls to `receiver1` and `receiver2`.

Ordinarily, I'd give up here, since Python's a dynamically typed language and it seems unreasonable to insist that an IDE structurally understand code that dispatches on dynamic type.

However, PyCharm can do that specialization; it just only seems to work with `isinstance` checks. If I replace `dispatch` with the below code, PyCharm type checks it correctly:

```py
def dispatch():
    item = get_item()
    if isinstance(item, Subtype1):
        receiver1(item)
    elif isinstance(item, Subtype2):
        receiver2(item)
    # ... many more cases
```

The problem is, that's too slow. `isinstance` itself is much slower than an `is` comparison, and I have to call it many times to check each case; there are many cases.

Is there a way to make PyCharm detect simple specialization types without using `isinstance`? If so, how?

## What I've tried

- Ordinarily, this would be a good fit for object orientation. If the `receiver` functions were instead methods on each subtype, I could simply call `item.recieve()` or something each time. However, the subtypes are declared in code I don't control (and are record classes implemented in C, so they can't be subclassed--weird, I know, but I did disclaim that it's performance-critical code :)).
- Various dispatch table approaches using a `dict` keyed by type with receiver methods as values similarly defeat PyCharm's type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give additional type hints to PyCharm

```
def dispatch():
    item = get_item()
    item_type = type(item)
    if item_type is Subtype1:
        item: Subtype1
        receiver1(item)
    elif item_type is Subtype2:
        item: Subtype2
        receiver2(item)
```

This should not affect performance of the code.

Another approach would be to inject the receiver method into Subtype1/2 classes:

```py
def receiver1(arg: Subtype1):
    print("receiver1 called")

def receiver2(arg: Subtype2):
    print("receiver2 called")

class MyMeta(type):
    pass

d = dict(Subtype1.__dict__)
d.update({"receiver": receiver1})
Subtype1 = MyMeta(Subtype1.__name__,
                  Subtype1.__bases__,
                  d)

d = dict(Subtype2.__dict__)
d.update({"receiver": receiver2})
Subtype2 = MyMeta(Subtype2.__name__,
                  Subtype2.__bases__,
                  d)

def dispatch():
    item = get_item()
    item.receiver()
```

Comment: That works. I'm hoping for a way which doesn't entail that amount of duplication, but if none presents itself (here or in my experimentation) I'll accept that. I'm on my way down the rabbit hole of PyCharm's internals presently, so give me a couple of days, but you're likely right that this is the only/best way.

Comment: I came along such problems with class properties when PyCharm could not detect the correct type of the underlying variable. Let's see what else comes up ...

Comment: I have added another solution that injects the receiver method into class Subtype1.

Comment: The second solution saves code, but doesn't address the problem of type hinting; this issue arose specifically because event publishers and receiver authors were requesting IDE assistance in making sure they called the right receivers for their events.

Comment: I was unable to find any solutions inside PyCharm itself, though an extremely perseverent extension author might. Accepting your first proposed solution (re-annotate variables next to each receiver call), thanks!

Comment: You're right, the second proposal is not about type hinting. Instead, it is about hard-wiring receivers to subtypes and avoiding the problem on a more fundamental level. Anyhow, you know what approach does better fit your needs..